# regexp in matlab

Tags: regex, string, matlab, replace, integer

I want to use regexp in matlab. I have an exemplary string `12nameofit2012.2.ending.mat`.
What i want to do is to detect and replace with nothing all signs in the beginning (this case `12`) and all before `.ending`, but NOT `2012`. (so, this case 2 after the dot). I guess i need some pattern from regexp and i guess it should be two consecutive lines, one detecting if there is any in the beginning:

```
regexprep(file_name, '^\d+', '')
```

but what to write for detection of the combination: `.` and integer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about using placeholders like this:

```
filename= '12nameofit2012.2.ending.mat'
reduced_name = regexprep(filename,'^\d+(.*?)(\.\d+)*(\.ending\.mat)$','$1$3')
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
regexprep(file_name, '\.\d+', '')
```